# React native app crashes on the Button click unexpectedly

Tags: android, react-native

Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.c
TypeError: undefined is not a function This error is located at: in E in Unknown in u in Unknown in RCTView in Unknown in Unknown in T in E in RCTView in Unknown in RCTView in Unknown in C, js engine: hermes, stack: y@2146:1172 wr@77:42102 Hl@77:89853 ja@77:79095 Ba@77:78997 Qa@77:78762 Ia@77:75924 anonymous@77:26326 anonymous@142:3806 ft@77:26045 ht@77:26273 pt@77:26208 ke@77:93329 _e@77:12979 Re@77:13368 receiveTouches@77:14167 value@41:3469 anonymous@41:662 value@41:2459 value@41:634

I am getting this error Tried with different solution but app crashes as i click on the button

I tried With this step option 1

1.(in project directory) mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
2.react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
this produce 2 files that fix the problem. if other files created delete them
for determines other files you can use git.
3.react-native run-android

I tried With this step option 2

Proguard was causing the app to crash, i temporarily disabled it and it worked like a charm.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
           // minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds <--- commented this line
           // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"),  "proguard-rules.pro" and this
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable true

        }
```

I tried With this step option 3

```
project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: 'packages/mobile/index.js',
        root: '../../../../',
        enableHermes: false,
        extraPackagerArgs: [ '--minify=false' ], //Add this!
]
```

Nothing worked please check and provide me any solution

Comment: Hi @Rambler , Have you got any solution?

Comment: Hi @Anuj yes i got the Solutions it was due to useEffect And the mistake was it was imported from another package Instead of the React.